# How to make an arrow with pseudoelement :before

Tags: html, css

I tried to make an arrow using the `:before` pseudoelement like this

```
a {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

a:before {
    content: '';
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 6px;
    border-left-color: grey;
}
```

For some reason the arrow is not what I expected (checkout this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SH55w/))
any suggestion how to turn this almost-an-arrow thing of mine into a smaller, vertically aligned pointing to the right arrow ?

Comment: Another [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SH55w/2/) for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add

> display: inline-block;

to a:before

Answer (score 1):

By using borders in creative way you may achieve this effect

```
.arrow-right {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 60px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;

    border-left: 60px solid green;
}
```

you may find original article here http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

or you may be looking for this http://jsfiddle.net/stowball/tjPQa/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

**Super simple!**

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/SH55w/1/)

Change your CSS to:

```
a {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
a:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    top:12px;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent grey;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

HTML

```
<div class="arrow-up"></div>
<div class="arrow-down"></div>
<div class="arrow-left"></div>
<div class="arrow-right"></div>
```

Css

```
.arrow-up {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;

    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

.arrow-down {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;

    border-top: 20px solid #f00;
}

.arrow-right {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 60px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;

    border-left: 60px solid green;
}

.arrow-left {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 

    border-right:10px solid blue; 
}
```

Here's the Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eyZRw/

Credit to ----> [css tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)